# Browser cache limit and max-age

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, web, browser

This might be a theoretical question but I would like to know what will happen if I set a max-age for a web resource for 5 days and browser's max cache limit reaches in 3 days.

- Is there a cache removal policy that will remove some cached resources(such as Least recently used)
- while cach limit has been reached if I make another request for a new resource will it get cached?